# UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS8 always shows in fullscreen

Tags: ios8, uipopovercontroller

When you press a button which is on a custom view, I want to show (width: 200, height:300) popover on iOS8. When I do this, I get the popover as fullscreen popover. (the delegate also does not work. it doesn't call `prepareForPopoverPresentation` etc...

How can I show the popover correctly with width:200, height=300 and what can be the problem with the delegate not calling?

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIView*)sender{
    CGRect rect=[self convertRect:sender.frame fromView:sender.superview];

    rect.origin.y-=10;

    rect.size.width=60;
    rect.size.height=60;

    self.stViewController=[[STViewController alloc]init];


    self.stViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

    self.stViewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPopover;
    self.stViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);

    if (self.stViewController.popoverPresentationController)
    {
        self.stViewController.popoverPresentationController.delegate=self;
        self.stViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView=self.superview;
        self.stViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect=rect;
        self.stViewController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight;

        [[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate mainViewController] presentViewController:self.stViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Comment: This works, but I must set delegate again everytime I present the view controller (with popover configured)

Comment: Maybe you are setting delegate to nil when popover is dismissed or about to be dismissed.